# Nginx access log with grok pattern

Tags: logstash, nginx-config, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

My nginx log format is as following, there certain log file will have empty value (such as without *request_time/hrrp_x_forwarded_for* and *http_host*), in this case, the grok pattern not working, it will not separate filter the message body but appear as a complete message, is there anyway to skip the empty value?

Example, if the *$request_time* is empty, skip this field and proceed with other.

````
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$request_time"  "$http_x_forwarded_for" $http_host ';```



grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:remote_ip} - %{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] \"%{WORD:method}%{DATA:url} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent:bytes} (?:\"(?:%{DATA:referrer}|-))\" \"%{DATA:agent}\" (?:\"(?:%{NUMBER:request_time}|-))\"  (?:\"(?:%{DATA:http_x_forwarded_for}|-))\" (?:%{IPORHOST:http_host}) " }
        remove_field => "message"
      
    }
````

Comment: there is no syntax error for the grok pattern, just all the filed with - /empty filed not working

Comment: You should be able to extend the Grok pattern.